# Can JMS guarantee that a message in the queue can received by only one instance of receiver at a time?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Let's say if there is one sender that sending 100 messages one by one to a queue and three receivers receiving the messages from the queue, is JMS by default to define the receivers will not pick up the same message so that each receiver will be assigned with different messages? or is it configurable to perform so?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you re frame the question please and I may be able to help you out.

Comment: @ Vishal P Thank you. just rephrase the question. :)

Comment: @Vishal P Pretty much it is about asking if JMS queue can manage the synchronization of the message receiving:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, consumers on queues always compete for messages.

topics on the other hand are publish/subscribe (all consumers get them).

If a consumer blows up and the message is redelivered; there is no guarantee the message will go to the same consumer.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Multiple queue senders and queue receivers can be associated with a single queue, but an individual message can be delivered to only one
>   queue receiver.*
>   *If multiple queue receivers are listening for messages on a queue, WebLogic JMS determines which one will receive the next message on a
>   first come, first serve basis. If no queue receivers are listening on
>   the queue, messages remain in the queue until a queue receiver
>   attaches to the queue"*

From [Weblogic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jms/fund.html)

Yes, only one listener would receieve message. If you want to send to multiple listeners use topic instead of Queue.